# Using the preview versions of asp.net core mvc in a class libary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am making an ASP.Net Core MVC app which handles multiple subdomains. Therefor I want to split up all Views/Controllers by their subdomain in a different project. What I am currently struggling at is referencing the latest pre-release of the ASP.Net Core framework in a .Net Core 3 Class Libary.

Now I do not know which nuget package I need to reference, in order to be able to have all the libraries needed for Controllers and Views.

I suspected that the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` nuget package would be all I need, but it is version `v2.2.0` instead of the pre-release one e.g. `3.0.0-preview9.19423.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0, MVC is part of the [Shared Framework](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/docs/SharedFramework.md). The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package is one of [many that will no longer be published separately](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756).

> To simplify the way in which consumers target and use the ASP.NET Core shared framework, we will stop producing many of the NuGet packages that we have been shipping since ASP.NET Core 1.0. The API those packages provide are still available to apps by using a `<FrameworkReference>` to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. This includes commonly referenced API, such as Kestrel, Mvc, Razor, and others.

Reference: [Breaking changes to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in 3.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325)